# `saveAsTextFile` method not working in spark standalone cluster

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using a 3 node standalone spark cluster with 1 master and 2 workers, along with a 2 node cassandra ring, here is a sample code of what I am trying to do

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true);
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(HOST, APP_NAME, conf);

String query = "Select address from " + CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE + "." + CASSANDRA_COLUMN_FAMILY + " where ras_ = '01'";

CassandraSQLContext sqlContext = new CassandraSQLContext(sc);
DataFrame resultsFrame = sqlContext.sql(query);

JavaRDD<Row> resultsRDD = resultsFrame.javaRDD();
JavaRDD<String> dataRDD = resultsRDD.map(row -> row.getString(0));

dataRDD.saveAsTextFile("output");
```

From the `System.out.println`, I know I have some data as a result of my query, but in my project home, in the `output` directory, the only files I am getting are `_SUCCESS` and `._SUCCESS.crc` and none of the `part-*` files. Is this expected behavior ? if not, where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Try to find out by minimizing the example! What happens if you remove `coalesce`? What happens if you use `sc.parallelize` instead of a Cassandra query as the input?

Comment: I have edited, and tried to minimize the example, and tried both with/without `repartition`/`coalesce`, as well as collecting the result in a List using `collect` and parallelizing it using `sc.parallelize`, still no luck. A directory named `output` is created in my project home, with only `_SUCCESS` and `._SUCCESS.crc`

Comment: I had the same problem when writing to a local file. Try writing into HDFS (dataRDD.saveAsTextFile(hdfs://...)) or Cassandra (dataRDD.saveToCassandra)

Comment: trying to save to hdfs gives `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:///user/root/output
`

Comment: I have it working with hdfs using a url of format `hdfs://host:9000/output/directory`. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like we have the same situation here since we both use more than one node, turns out the file is not guaranteed to save on which node.

In my case, it was not saved on the master which i run the script but one of the slaves.

Hope helpful.